# "No SKUs listed, can't load them" - solovyev.android:checkout

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase

I have an app with in-app purchase, but when I try get list of items I recieving error:

> Caused by: org.solovyev.android.checkout.Check$AssertionException: No
>   SKUs listed, can't load them

InAppPurchase.java:

```
import android.app.Application;

import org.solovyev.android.checkout.Billing;

public class InAppPurchase extends Application {
    private static InAppPurchase sInstance;
    String key = "xxx";
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    private final Billing mBilling = new Billing(this, new Billing.DefaultConfiguration() {
        @Override public String getPublicKey() {
            return key;
        }
    });

    public InAppPurchase() {
        sInstance = this;
    }

    public static InAppPurchase get() {
        return sInstance;
    }

    public Billing getBilling() {
        return mBilling;
    }
}
```

Settings.java:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
...

 mCheckout = Checkout.forActivity(this, InAppPurchase.get().getBilling());
        mCheckout.start();
        mCheckout.createPurchaseFlow(new PurchaseListener());
        Inventory mInventory = mCheckout.makeInventory();
        mInventory.load(
                Inventory.Request.create().loadAllPurchases().loadSkus(ProductTypes.IN_APP),
                new InventoryCallback());
...
}

private class InventoryCallback implements Inventory.Callback {
        @Override public void onLoaded(@Nonnull Inventory.Products products) {
            final Inventory.Product product = products.get(ProductTypes.IN_APP);
            if (!product.supported) {
                Toast.makeText(Settings.this, "error supported", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            List<Purchase> list = product.getPurchases();
                if (product.getSku("dark_theme") != null) {
                    String price = product.getSku("dark_theme").price;
                    Toast.makeText(Settings.this, price, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
        }
```

And error for

> No SKUs listed, can't load them

Is showing in line

```
Inventory.Request.create().loadAllPurchases().loadSkus(ProductTypes.IN_APP)
```

App publihed in Alpha-section n Google Dev Console.

Please help me to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to provide a Sku id, you want to retrieve

```
mInventory.load(Inventory.Request.create().loadAllPurchases().loadSkus(ProductTypes.IN_APP),"<your Google Play product Id>",
            new InventoryCallback());
```